# More than 2 rules for return in def() Python

Tags: python, if-statement, return

If I create a function like this is any possible way to add more `if`, `elif` statements? `continue` for negative number or `break` for big values in one big line? Without `if:if:` tree? 
factorial() only for example.

```
from functools import reduce

def factorial(n):
    """return n!"""
    return 1 if n<2 else reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, {i+1 for i in range(n)})
```

Comment: This is a classic.  "Yes, but why?"

Comment: Something like `return "negative" if n < 0 else 1 if n == 1 else reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, {i+1 for i in range(n)}) ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Each part in the `a if b else c` ternary expression is an expression, which can again be a ternary, thus you can chain many ternaries onto each other, e.g. `a if b else c if d else e`. Without parentheses, evaluation order is from left to right, i.e. just as you'd read it, but you can also add parens and e.g. use a ternary for the condition. Whether that's very readable is another question.

Speaking of readability: While you can chain them, you might consider not chaining them all in a single line, for a better compromise between brevity and readability:

```
def factorial(n):
    return -1 if n < 0 else \
            1 if n < 2 else \
            n * factorial(n-1)
```

Remember the line continuation `\` or put parens around the entire expression. However, note that neither `continue` nor `break` can be used, as those only work inside of loops.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use if-elif-else structure rather than a conditional expression:

```
def factorial(n):
   if n<0:
       return None
   elif n<=1:
       return 1
   else:
       return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, {i+1 for i in range(n)})
```

Comment: yes, but I want to make it in one line and if I need edit code with new statement  I don't need to refactor all function. It's not about a problem, it's about how we can edit our code and understanding how python works.